# std::filesystem::weakly_canonical() does not seem to work with drive letters

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path("C:");
    std::filesystem::path canonicalPath = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(path);
    std::cout << canonicalPath.string() << std::endl;
}
```

produces the output:
`C:\Users\andy\source\repos\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8`
using Visual Studio 2019 X64.
On x86-64 gcc it produces what I expect: `C:` according to godbolt.org.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows and Linux have different rules when it comes to paths.

For example, on Windows using the drive-letter and colon only means *the current directory* on the specified drive. This behavior is inherited from DOS.

When you build using GCC on the compiler explorer, it uses a virtual Linux environment, and Linux doesn't have drive letters. Which means that `C:` isn't a path in Linux, but rather a file-name.